# Como fazer requisições ao Core Data para pegar somente um atributo?

Tags: banco-de-dados, ios, objective-c, query, core-data

Preciso somente pegar um atributo de uma única linha da tabela:

```
 name  | id   | idade  | aprov|repro| sala | 
_______|______|________|______|_____|______| 
John   |  32  |    15  |   A  |     | 155  |
```

Seguindo a tabela acima, seria o campo `idade` contendo o elemento `15`.

Como posso fazer isso usando Core Data?

No caso este app é para iOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter somente a coluna **idade** você define o método `setPropertiesToFetch:` do seu objeto `NSFetchRequest`, algo assim:

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"idade", nil]];
```

E para fazer o filtro, um `NSPredicate`:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"id == %d", 32];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
```

E assim realiza o resto da sua requisição que vai retornar um único objeto, de acordo com o **id**.

Comment: Mas deste modo ele vai me trazer uma coluna inteira, no caso um NSArray, agora que dei uma olhada, e repensei, preciso que ele me traga especificamente uma LINHA e uma COLUNA, para trazer somente um único elemento. Entendeu?

Comment: Ok, sendo assim acrescentei essa implementação na minha resposta.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, vou testar e te retorno se funcionou ou não!

Comment: funcionou, mas a informação que eu queria pegar não é acessível, pois queria acessar a Primary Key gerada pelo core data, no caso ela aparece na tabela como Z_PK. Deu um erro dizendo que ela não está disponível na tabela que estou usando :/

Comment: O atributo `Z_PK` não é um campo qualquer que você utiliza no *Core Data*. Você não depende desse valor para manter a consistência da sua base, até porque o *schema* pode e vai mudar a cada atualização do seu aplicativo, é por isso que esse valor não fica acessível. Qual a necessidade de obtê-lo?

Comment: Meu app tem 2 tabelas, e uma delas somente vai possuir um registro, ou seja uma Z_PK somente de valor 1. 

 Que será o registro do usuário, e o app para preencher a segunda tabela, precisará dos dados do usuário que estão na primeira. Entendeu?

Comment: Mas de todos os itens do usuário, o mais usado será o campo ID_REGISTRO da linha 1 no caso

Comment: Entenda que o atributo `Z_PK` é de uso interno do *Core Data*, tanto que você não o cria no **Xcode**, você só consegue enxergá-lo se extrair o banco **SQLite** do seu aplicativo. Então o relacionamento da forma que você está procurando fazer com esse atributo tem que ser repensado.

Comment: Sim já repensei: O registro do user somente acontecerá uma única vez, então apenas terei somente 1 registro. Então ao fazer a requisição eu somente terei um registro para o NSArray, portanto é somente oque quero rs :D